# Остановить автоматическое прекращение работы Laravel job при блоке try

Tags: laravel

У меня есть laravel job, который запускает очень много процессов, и это среднем занимает по несколько дней(парсинг), у меня есть в коде такой блок:

```
try{
                    $link = DB::table('links')->insert(['url'=>$url]);
                } finally {
                }
```

На  DB::table('links'), атрибут url стоит unique, и я просто ставлю его в try finally (если есть в базе то не добавлять)
Почему при запуске queue:work, он доходит до try finally, или try catch, он остановляваеться, почему тогда надо try? мне нужно чтобы он не прекращал работу при блоке try, не пойму не как, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Ну вообще можете добавить `return` а в целом не логичней ли вначале будет проверить наличие? `DB::table('links')->where('url', $url')->exists()`? try нужен  для отлова ошибок и изменения поведения приложения в случае наличия той или иной ошибки

Comment: А это будет добполнительный запрос к дб

Comment: Сделайте тогда insert ignore